# When were JAR files first created?

Tags: java, history

When were JAR files first created? Was that in Java 1.0 or a later edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JAR File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29), [JAR File Format](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/) and [JAR File Specification](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jar/jar.html) sheds some light on this topics.

`The JAR file format was introduced in version 1.1 of the Java Development Kit, and version 1.2 includes several enhancements to JAR file functionality. Unless otherwise noted, features covered in this trail pertain to both versions 1.1 and 1.2. If a feature description or example pertains only to one version, you'll be alerted with an annotation such as "version 1.2."`

Answer (score 2):

JAR file (ZIP files, renamed to have a JAR file extension) were introduced in Java 1.1  http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/

Comment: Then the 1.0 JRE's had N loose-class files floating about? O.o

Comment: @pst: Yes, there was just a large directory tree created by the installer with several thousand files.

Comment: @pst Yes.  Been there, had to deal with it, especially in the Java applet days.

Comment: I remember those days well. The first time I heard about jar files was when I got picked up to do some J2EE programming around 2003. I'm sure I would have respected them more had I not been also dealing with WAR, EAR, and countless other packages.